# Monogame; Cannot override any methods that have SpriteBatch as parameter

Tags: xamarin.android, xna-4.0, monogame

Pretty new to monogame (mono for android to be precise) but with some youtube tutorials the process was fairly pain free.
I'm trying to override some functions (from an "XNA library project" dll) I can override all the functions just fine. But when I try to override anything that passes in a SpriteBatch as an argument I get the follow error:

> Error 5   'Parkour.Screens.EditorScreen.Draw(Microsoft.Xna.Framework.Graphics.SpriteBatch)':
>   no suitable method found to override  D:\Data\programming and
>   such\comps\TIGsport\XNA\Parkour\Parkour\Parkour\Screens\EditorScreen.cs   117 30  ParkourAndroid

I'm absolutely sure the method is there, because the XNA project works just fine. 
The Draw function also pops up in autocorrect in the mono for android project. But strange enough it seems to have dissapeared from autocorrect after I received the error.

Here is the entire class which holds the to be override function, just so you guys can be sure nothing is wrong.

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using Microsoft.Xna.Framework.Graphics;

namespace SimpleTilebasedLibrary.Utils
{
    public class LoopContainer<T> where T : ILoopable
    {
        protected List<T> _items = new List<T>();
        private List<T> _addList = new List<T>();
        private List<T> _removeList = new List<T>();

        public List<T> items
        {
            get{return _items;}
        }

        public virtual void add(T item)
        {
            //if (_addList.Contains(item)) return;
            //_addList.Add(item);
            _items.Add(item);
        }

        public virtual void remove(T item)
        {
            if (_removeList.Contains(item)) return;
            _removeList.Add(item);
        }

        public T get(int index)
        {
            return _items[index];
        }

        public T get(string name)
        {
            foreach (T item in items)
            {
                if (item.getName() == name)
                {
                    return item;
                }
            }

            return default(T);
        }

        public virtual void Update()
        {
            items.AddRange(_addList);
            _addList.Clear();

            foreach (T item in items)
            {
                if (item.status == Status.DEAD)
                {
                    _removeList.Add(item);
                    //break; //root of all evil
                    continue;
                }

                item.Update();
            }

            //remove
            foreach (T i in _removeList)
            {
                items.Remove(i);
            }
            _removeList.Clear();

        }

        public virtual void postUpdate()
        {
            foreach (T item in items)
            {
                item.postUpdate();
            }
        }

        public virtual void Draw(SpriteBatch spritebatch)
        {
            foreach (T item in items)
            {
                item.Draw(spritebatch);
            }
        }
    }
}
```

And the class that is trying to override it

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using SimpleTilebasedLibrary;
using SimpleTilebasedLibrary.Entities;
using SimpleTilebasedLibrary.Tilesystem;
using SimpleTilebasedLibrary.Services;
using Microsoft.Xna.Framework.Input;
using SimpleTilebasedLibrary.Components;
using SimpleTilebasedLibrary.Utils;
using SimpleTilebasedLibrary.UI;
using Microsoft.Xna.Framework;
using Microsoft.Xna.Framework.Graphics;

namespace Parkour.Screens
{
    public class EditorScreen : GameScreen //need to couple gamescreens with inputcontexts?
    {
        public ParkourWorld world;
        int currentTile = 0;
        GameObject tile;

        Checkbox editorEnabled;
        Checkbox solidCB;
        Checkbox autotileCB;

        public EditorScreen(ParkourWorld world)
            : base("editorscreen")
        {
            this.world = world;
            tile = new GameObject("tileset", 16, 16); //never actually tested this, doesn't work!
            tile.GetC<GraphicsC>().setScale(2, 2);
            //add(tile); //something fucks up the coordinates when you add it...

            editorEnabled = new Checkbox(Color.White, 10);
            editorEnabled.GetC<TransformC>().Y = 10;
            editorEnabled.GetC<TransformC>().X = 100;

            solidCB = new Checkbox(Color.Red, 10);
            solidCB.GetC<TransformC>().Y = 10;//30;
            solidCB.GetC<TransformC>().X = 120;
            //add(solidCB);

            autotileCB = new Checkbox(Color.Blue, 10);
            autotileCB.GetC<TransformC>().Y = 10;//50;
            autotileCB.GetC<TransformC>().X = 140;
            //add(autotileCB);

            editorEnabled.value = false;
        }


        public override void Update()
        {
            base.Update();

            if (GameServices.get<InputManager>().hasScrolledDown() && currentTile > 0)
            {
                currentTile--;
            }

            if (GameServices.get<InputManager>().hasScrolledUp() && currentTile < tile.GetC<GraphicsC>().totalFrames - 1) 
            {
                currentTile++;
                Console.WriteLine(currentTile);
            }

            tile.GetC<GraphicsC>().gotoAndStop(currentTile);

            //


            if (Mouse.GetState().LeftButton == ButtonState.Pressed && editorEnabled.value)
            {
                GameCamera camera = GameServices.get<CameraManager>().getActiveCamera();

                int x = TileMath.PixelToTile((Mouse.GetState().X + (camera.GetC<CameraC>().leftX * camera.GetC<CameraC>().zoom)) / camera.GetC<CameraC>().zoom, world.tilegrid.tileWidth);
                int y = TileMath.PixelToTile((Mouse.GetState().Y + (camera.GetC<CameraC>().UpY * camera.GetC<CameraC>().zoom)) / camera.GetC<CameraC>().zoom, world.tilegrid.tileHeight);

                if (Keyboard.GetState().IsKeyDown(Keys.Z))
                {
                    world.tilegrid.setTile(x, y, 0, null);
                    //world.tilegrid.getTile(x, y, 0).id = 1;
                    //world.tilegrid.getTile(x, y, 0).solid = false;
                }
                else
                {
                    Tile t = world.tilegrid.setTile(x, y, 0, currentTile);
                    if (t != null) t.solid = solidCB.value;

                    if(autotileCB.value)world.tilegrid.AutoTile(t, 0, x, y, true);
                    //world.tilegrid.setTile(x, y, 0, null);
                }
            }

            // enable and disable cb's //
            if (GameServices.get<InputManager>().wasKeyPressed(Keys.LeftShift))
            {
                solidCB.value = !solidCB.value;
            }

            if (GameServices.get<InputManager>().wasKeyPressed(Keys.Q))
            {
                autotileCB.value = !autotileCB.value;
            }

            if (GameServices.get<InputManager>().wasKeyPressed(Keys.E))
            {
                editorEnabled.value = !editorEnabled.value;
            }

            solidCB.Update();
            autotileCB.Update();
        }

        public override void Draw(SpriteBatch spritebatch)
        {
            base.Draw(spritebatch);
            tile.Draw(spritebatch);
            editorEnabled.Draw(spritebatch);
            solidCB.Draw(spritebatch);
            autotileCB.Draw(spritebatch);

            CameraC camera = GameServices.get<CameraManager>().getActiveCameraC();

            int width = TileMath.PixelToTile(camera.viewrect.Left + camera.viewrect.Width + (world.tilegrid.tileWidth * 2), world.tilegrid.tileWidth);
            int height = TileMath.PixelToTile(camera.viewrect.Top + camera.viewrect.Height + (world.tilegrid.tileHeight * 2), world.tilegrid.tileHeight);

            if (editorEnabled.value)
            {
                spritebatch.End();
                spritebatch.Begin(SpriteSortMode.Deferred, null, SamplerState.PointClamp, null, null, null, GameServices.get<CameraManager>().getActiveCameraC().getTransformation());

                //getTile(width - 1, 0).GetComponent<GraphicsC>().sprite.gotoAndStop(4);

                Rectangle rect = new Rectangle();
                Color trans = new Color(255, 0, 0, 10);
                for (int x = TileMath.PixelToTile(camera.viewrect.Left, world.tilegrid.tileWidth); x < width; x++)
                {
                    for (int y = TileMath.PixelToTile(camera.viewrect.Top, world.tilegrid.tileHeight); y < height; y++)
                    {
                        if (world.tilegrid.getTile(x, y, 0) != null)
                        {
                            if (!world.tilegrid.getTile(x, y, 0).solid) continue;
                            rect.X = x * world.tilegrid.tileWidth;
                            rect.Y = y * world.tilegrid.tileHeight;
                            rect.Width = world.tilegrid.tileWidth;
                            rect.Height = world.tilegrid.tileHeight;
                            spritebatch.Draw(GameServices.get<AssetManager>().CreateColoredTexture(trans), rect, Color.White);
                        }
                    }
                }

                spritebatch.End();
                spritebatch.Begin();
            }
        }


    }


}
```

There is alot of useless stuff in there for you guys, but I wanted to include it just for the sake of completeness.

I have the exact same problem with another class that has a Draw(SpriteBatch) function that needs to be overriden.

Comment: Does 'GameScreen' inherit from 'LoopContainer<T>' some where along the line or does it contain it's own 'Draw(SpriteBatch spriteBatch)' method? You can't 'override' a method on another class with no relationship between them

Comment: Could you please include the code for your 'GameScreen'

Comment: I realize that my code wasn't really clear. Yes it inherrits from GameScreen.

On another note, I think I might have found out what the problem is, but I am not completely sure. The dll that I'm loading in has been compiled with the XNA framework. Maybe I should first compile it in a monogame project? I guess the base function is requiring a Microsoft SpriteBatch, while EditorScreen has a MonoGame SpriteBatch parameter?

Comment: Both XNA and MonoGame should have the same method signature, but yes instead of referencing the compiled DLL, pull in the library into your solution and reference MonoGame. I don't think that will be the problem, but could be.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Turned out that I was passing in a MonoGame spritebatch where the library was requiring an XNA spritebatch. I recompiled the library in a seperate project with MonoGame and all problems are sovled.